# Why call getUserInfo if I can get the same from id_token?

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

According to the documentation (https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-token#control-the-contents-of-an-id-token) it is possible to ask for an id_token containing the user's profile, e-mail...

So why would I be calling `getUserInfo` as shown in the example https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11#2-authenticating-and-getting-user-info ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your scenario is but imagine a Single Page Application (SPA) in combination with a backend API.

**TL;DR**

the backend API should use the `access_token` + `/userinfo`. The `id_token` is convenience for the frontend application.

**Some more details:**

Suppose you do the authentication directly in the SPA. This yields and `access_token` and an `id_token`.

The `id_token` can be used by the SPA to show some extra information (nickname, email, ...).

Now what if the SPA wants to make a call the a protected endpoint in the backend API?

A possibility here would be that it passes the `access_token` in the Authorization header (e.g. `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c` [see jwt.io](https://jwt.io))

So the backend should:

- verify the `access_token`.

For example using the [JSON Web Key Set](https://auth0.com/docs/jwks) (`https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/.well-known`)

- call `/userinfo` to fetch the **real** user information, e.g. [Auth0 Get User Info](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info)

  ```
  GET https://<YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN>/userinfo
  Authorization: 'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}'
  ```

You *can* also pass the `id_token` (in a custom header or as payload) but the backend should not trust that information (the end user could have forged it for example by changing the `id_token` and claiming she is a superadmin user instead of a regular user).